# Docker Daemon connected to socket on :2375

Tags: sockets, docker, systemd

I have configured the systemd of my Docker version 1.12 to listen on port :2375.

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP
MountFlags=slave
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity
Delegate=yes
# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As a result:

```
*tcp6       0      0 :::2375                 :::*                    LISTEN*
```

However, when I try to use the 'docker' command at the terminal of the host I am running the Docker on, I get the following:

```
    [root@docker1-12 ~]# docker images
    Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

Even though the docker.service is actually running:

● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-12-30 14:50:53 AEDT; 1min 32s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 4976 (dockerd)
   Memory: 21.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─4976 /usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
           └─4982 docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --shim docker-containerd-shim --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --runtime do...

Dec 30 14:50:52 docker1-12 dockerd[4976]: time="2016-12-30T14:50:52.083736426+11:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver \"devicemapper\""
Dec 30 14:50:52 docker1-12 dockerd[4976]: time="2016-12-30T14:50:52.091254467+11:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Dec 30 14:50:52 docker1-12 dockerd[4976]: time="2016-12-30T14:50:52.095445562+11:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Dec 30 14:50:52 docker1-12 dockerd[4976]: time="2016-12-30T14:50:52.128643621+11:00" level=info msg="Firewalld running: true"
Dec 30 14:50:52 docker1-12 dockerd[4976]: time="2016-12-30T14:50:52.919797126+11:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Dec 30 14:50:53 docker1-12 dockerd[4976]: time="2016-12-30T14:50:53.274835533+11:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Dec 30 14:50:53 docker1-12 dockerd[4976]: time="2016-12-30T14:50:53.275468481+11:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Dec 30 14:50:53 docker1-12 dockerd[4976]: time="2016-12-30T14:50:53.275501250+11:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=7392c3b graphdriver=devicemapper version=1.12.5
Dec 30 14:50:53 docker1-12 dockerd[4976]: time="2016-12-30T14:50:53.285288956+11:00" level=info msg="API listen on [::]:2375"
Dec 30 14:50:53 docker1-12 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
```

How can I fix this? i.e. Have docker listening on port :2375 while being able to run docker commands locally on the host?

**NOTE**
I found the following configuration, as a workaround. However, this does not seem to work for Docker version 1.12:

```
Environment="DOCKER_OPTS=-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd://  \$DOCKER_OPTS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of 2 options:

1.Change your `systemd` unit file:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

This way, you will listen on tcp for network `API` calls and on the `unix sock` for local `docker cli`.

2.When trying to connect using `docker cli` use the following:

```
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
docker ps
```

Same effect one liner:

```
sudo docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 ps
```

Comment: Thank you @Farhad Farahi, sir. The second method worked like a charm. I added the 0.0.0.0:2375 to my /etc/environment under no_proxy since I am using a proxy on this instance. Thanks again for your help.